# Is Address to Uint256 unique in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

I'm using this function to convert address to uint to use as an id, is that id unique?

```
function toUint(address self) internal pure returns(uint256) {
    return uint256(uint160(self));
}
```

*I know we can use address as an id, but my concept require an unit*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uint is the base10 representation of the address. There are 2^256 possible addresses and the max of uint256 is 2^256 with a one to one relationship. So yes the id you get will be unique.

Correction: as 0xSanson has pointed out, the possible addresses are 2^160 as we are essentially casting to uint160 but the addresses should still generate unique int Ids

Comment: 2**160 possible addresses